# Caret Blink Rate

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, caret

I have created a user control that has an image that I would like to "blink" at the same rate as the user caret. This can be set using keyboard settings in the control panel on windows systems.

Are there any classes that will help me obtain this value?

I always thought the default was .5 seconds, however this is faster than desired and can be modified.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, answer for people looking in the future.

```
SystemInformation.CaretBlinkTime
```